# jQuery.get vs <script async src="...">

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you're using jQuery, is there any reason to use one of these methods to load a JavaScript file rather than the other?

```
$.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js');
```

vs

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

Comment: There is no functional difference between *those* two examples. But getScript is obviously shorter and provides an optional callback too. `async = true` is the default option and is redundant in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `$.getScript` performs a ["script" `$.ajax` request](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js) and runs through the `$.ajax` pipeline, so if you register any settings and handlers through $`.ajaxSetup` or `$.ajaxError` they will run.

For example, the following will cause scripts from `$.getScript` to be cached to the local memory:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```